# Magento Import cause Image missing

Tags: image, magento, csv, import

We simply export and amend several "item description" , import csv back

all Base/ thumbnail / small image linking are gone

in item page all photos still exist but the"key picture" show nothing

tried force save CSV on excel to UTF8 format, not a solution.

Comment: one more clue, I'd test export all products and immediately import that file (nothing amend), all Base/ thumbnail / small gone

Comment: some say its a known bug: http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/224928/

Comment: looks okay using dataflow approach instead

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, you need to reindex and clean the cache.

Go to System -> Cache management, flush the image cache and Magento cache. Refresh all caches. Then reindex in System -> Index Management.

Comment: have you cleaned all caches ?

Comment: some clue, when I export product today, all Base/ thumbnail / small image are blank, thats mean in database they are really nothing linked (my import file are not blank on those fields)

Comment: yes Jevgeni, all caches, I guess problem probably goes to the media/cataglog/ product folder VS import folder, by default when we manager product in magento, photo goes to former one, but tutorial we search said import via csv need files in later one, I'm confuse

Answer (score 0):

We have had a lot of success with Magmi: http://sourceforge.net/projects/magmi/  in terms of first time importing and updating product images.

http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/magmi/index.php?title=Image_attributes_processor